# Java arrays: select and replace values via user inputs

Tags: java, arrays, user-input, replace

In the program I'm creating, the user will input values to create an array of videos. Each video contains several data fields (number, title, publisher, duration & date). However what I am currently trying to acheive is to let the user choose a particular video in the array they just created, select the data field they wish to rename, rename the value and then set the renamed value as the new value. Here is my code for adding videos to an array:

```
public Library createLibrary()
{
    Library video = new Library();
    java.util.Scanner scannerObject =new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
    for (int i = 0; i < videos.length; i++)
    {
    //User enters values into set methods within the Library class
    System.out.print("Enter video number: " + (i+1) + "\n");
    String number = scannerObject.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter video title: " + (i+1) + "\n");
    String title = scannerObject.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter video publisher: " + (i+1) + "\n");
    String publisher = scannerObject.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter video duration: " + (i+1) + "\n");
    String duration = scannerObject.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter video date: " + (i+1) + "\n");
    String date= scannerObject.nextLine();
    System.out.print("VIDEO " + (i+1) + " ENTRY ADDED " + "\n \n");
    //Initialize arrays
    videos[i] = new Library ();
    videos[i].setVideo( number, title, publisher, duration, date  );
    }
    return video;
}
```

And here is the basic concept for my select and replace function for those who can't figure out what I mean:

```
public void replaceVideo(Library[] videos, String replaceTo, String replaceWith) 
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) 
        if (videos[i].equals(replaceTo)) {
            videos[i]= replaceWith;
        }
    }
```

Simpler solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing `replaceTo` to the name of the video (or whatever `replaceTo` is supposed to match):

```
if (videos[i].getName().equals(replaceTo)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your replace ever working, since it appears that you are comparing a Library type and a String type with .equals().

If you use one of the Collection classes instead of an array, the replace method changes to

```
public void replaceVideo(Vector<Library> videos, Library current, Library newCopy)
{
  Collections.replaceAll(videos, current, newCopy);
}
```

I used Vector, but you could use a Set, List, etc. as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, you need to override the Library.equals method to compare strings only. Otherwise, you can compare the video title, for one sample, against the parameter replaceTo.

Certainly, it is OOP elegant to override the equals method. Try my suggestion and Thomas'

Good luck.